# Trying to Automatically read the OTP from the incoming message for react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

My objective : I am trying to automatically fill the OTP code from the incoming message(SMS) in my react native app.

So far I only get the SMS from the backend but  I am not able to read the SMS (which contains the OTP) in my react native app.

In verification.js (User enters the phone number) and in Otp screen.js  (the OTP code should get populated).

1. In the Verification.js I also added the permissions required to read and receive the sms, from the user.
2. In the OtpScreen.js we have registered a sms listener but the call back function doesn't get executed (which is responsible for reading the incoming message).

```
//AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
```

```
//Verification.js
useEffect(() => {
    async function requestReadSmsPermission() {
      console.log('the sms');
      try {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
          PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_SMS,
          {
            title: ' Read SMS Permission',
            message: 'Allow Our app to read your SMS?',
            buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
            buttonPositive: 'OK'
          }
        );
        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
          console.log('You can Read  the SMS');
        } else {
          console.log('Read SMS permission denied');
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err);
      }
    }
    requestReadSmsPermission();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function requestReceiveSmsPermission() {
      console.log('the sms');
      try {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
          PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.RECEIVE_SMS,
          {
            title: ' Receive SMS Permission',
            message: 'Allow Our App to receive your SMS?',
            buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
            buttonPositive: 'OK'
          }
        );
        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
          console.log('You can receive  the SMS');
        } else {
          console.log('receive SMS permission denied');
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err);
      }
    }
    requestReceiveSmsPermission();
  }, []);
```

I am providing the below snippet of my code:

```
//OtpScreen.js
useEffect(() => {
   _onSmsListener = async () => {
     try {
       const registered = await SmsRetriever.startSmsRetriever();
       if (registered) { // this becomes true
         console.log('SMS listener', registered);
         SmsRetriever.addSmsListener(event => {
           console.log(event.message); //I am not able to get the sms message here.
           SmsRetriever.removeSmsListener();
         });
       }
     } catch (error) {
       console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
     }
   };
```

PS:I have used the react-native-sms-retriever package.

Is there a way to use native Android code to implement this?

Is there any configuration that has to be done to read the SMS messages or do the messages have to be in a particular format? If yes, how do I format the messages?

Comment: What's OTP-Code? One-Time-Password?

Comment: @suther Yes , it is One time password

Comment: Could you explain a bit more, what exactly you try to do? I don't see, how OTP is in dependency with some sms. What exactly you try to do? Am I right, that your Backend-Application send an SMS which contain OTP as data for the SMS-Message?
So if yes, you better respell your request and remove the OTP-Stuff of your question and only write something like "I can't access the content of the received SMS-Message". The case, for what you use the SMS-Message data isn't relevant for giving you helping hands.

Else it's much confusing for people who wan't to support you to see what you mean.